# Is it possible to notify user by email when a new apk/aab file version is released to Play Store internal testing lane?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any setting in the Google Play Store Console where I can add a list of emails which should receive an email with information about the app when a new app version of Android app is released in internal testing lane?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a way to do this but you could use [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) if you really wants this feature.

Comment: No I want it on playstore

Comment: Then No you can not do this on playstote alone.